# Angularjs - How to access scope from $routeChangeSuccess?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**UPDATE**

Thanks everyone for your thoughts and comments. I think the best approach here given my project needs is actually to use a different framework that will give me better control over all the custom animations I need to add. Unfortunately, out of the box, I don't think I can get the hooks I need from Angular that I could get in Backbone.Marionette. Additionally, my other team members have all used Marionette before, so I think it just makes more sense all around.

To explain a bit better, as my question did not actually address my main issue, I need to have complex animations happen to various elements on my pages both as they get rendered, and also before they leave. I am guessing this is possible with Angular, but not out of the box, as far as I can tell. Unfortunately, I don't think I can spend any more time on trying to make it work.

Also, in an effort to try other animation techniques, I updated the fiddle to use addClass and removeClass animations. But I can't seem to get them to fire as I would expect. The removeClass animation runs consistently, but not the addClass animation. Toggle between page1 and page2 to trigger the directive to addClass and removeClass.

http://jsfiddle.net/jgS4W/2/

Seems weird to me.

**End of Update**

-

Okay, I've been at this for 2 days now with no success... What I'm trying to do is add custom JS animations to a view when it gets rendered in an ng-view container.

I've come close a couple times, but every time I fall short.

I was hoping that I could use the $routeChangeSuccess handler to access the scope of the current view and emit a 'view.enter' event, but that isn't working. The 'current' argument in the handler never has access to the scope of its view.

I've created a jsfiddle to explain what I'm talking about:
http://jsfiddle.net/jgS4W/

I would think that the following would work...

`$rootScope.$on('routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
  current.scope.$emit('view.enter');
]);`

But 'current.scope' is always undefined.

I've tried hooking into the animation events on the ng-view, but they are tied to the scope of the ng-view and not the scope of the view being rendered...

I'm at a loss here. How can I get events emitting when a view is being rendered???

Thanks!

Comment: as far as I'm aware the view is loaded by the same event, so your timing will always be off. kind of wondering why you're trying to trigger an event because of an event though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you're not getting the scope is because it doesn't exist yet. I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgS4W/1/) to demonstrate that.

Depending on your needs you could take a different approach and use a parent controller and/or a shared service instance that maintains some state values, which you can use to make the animation.

*Seems that stackoverflow enforces a line of code when linking to a fiddle, so here it goes*

```
// this is a single line of code
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think this would make the most sense in terms of answering my original question. I've changed course (updated my question) to using a different framework as I've decided the angular support for the extensiveness of animations I will need is not quite there yet. I'm marking this as the correct answer because I think it is the best solution for my original question and  helped explain why my original fiddle wasn't working to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on( "$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, next, current) {
  $rootScope.$broadcast('view.enter')
});
```

since you are in the $rootScope, you should broadcast the event, not the emit.

Within the controller you are in, you will have available the view.enter event:

```
$scope.$on('view.enter', function() {
  // Use your event somehow
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I tried this out, and I believe as @null pointed out, because the $scope doesn't yet exist when the event is being broadcast, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tbbgzfu5/

I have moved the 'routeChangeSuccess' event listener to the controller like so, and you can see that scope is found as it is getting scope from controller.

Does this solved the issue you are trying to fix?

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.something = 'some value'; 
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
        console.log($scope, 'current.scope');   
    });
});
```